# How to minify HTML block in JavaScript / jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, regex, minify

I have HTML coming from templates that I need to remove spaces between elements and new lines. I don't want to remove spaces that would break the HTML, so it is becoming tricky for me. So far I have the below to remove new lines, but spaces I am stuck on:

```
'<div id="head"></div> \n   <div id="body"></div>    <div id="foot"></div> '.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm, '');
```

Is there hopefully something built into jQuery instead of a complex regex maybe to remove the spaces?

Comment: Don't know web stuff but is it possible to parse it with a dom, edit the elements, then reconstruct it? Because finding a _tag_ can be quite complex. Its not like you can reliably use (in the case of tags) `/(>)\s+|\s+(<)/`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This should work :

```
.replace(/^\s+|\r\n|\n|\r|(>)\s+(<)|\s+$/gm, '$1$2')
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5WDVC/1/)

Comment: Don't forget to `$.trim` the wrapping whitespace in the original string if you're going to do it this way.